# JSON Datetime to time only

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Datime format of `"DateTime":"\/Date(1342572780000)\/"`

How can I change in to a 24 hour time format only?

Comment: On the server or in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The number you have in there "1342572780000" is the number of milliseconds since January 1 1970. You can convert that to standard form by using:

```
var thisDate = new Date(1342572780000);
```

`thisDate` is a `Date` object and you can manipulate it as you like, look at this reference:

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm

Comment: you could simplify that to `var thisDate = newDate(1342572780000);`
In addition you'll have to base 10 parseInt the JSON value because that's a string. Assuming `data` is your JSON decoded data.
`var thisDate = new Date(parseInt(data.DateTime, 10));`

You can then adjust to the 24-hour format via the instance methods on the Date class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/)

Comment: Don't set the milliseconds, supply the number directly to date per Matt Lo's comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function DateToTime(date) {
        function numTo2(n) {
            var s = n.toString();
            if (n.toString().length == 1) {
                s = "0" + n;
            }
            return s;
        }
        var time = numTo2(date.getHours()) + ":" + numTo2(date.getMinutes()) + ":" + numTo2(date.getSeconds());
        return time;
    }

    var data = { "DateTime": "\/Date(1342572780000)\/" };
    var date = new Date(data.DateTime.search(/\d/));
    var time = DateToTime(date);
```

Then you got time = `08:00:00`

Comment: Don't bother with *toLocaleTimeString*, many browsers simply ignore system and regional settings and suppy a US–centric date format.

Comment: Then you can use the first one, get the hour minute seconds and make your time string.